# How to use SQL "LIKE" operator in SLICK

Tags: scala, scalaquery, slick

Maybe a silly question. But I have not found an answer so far. So how do you represent the SQL's "LIKE" operator in **[SLICK](http://slick.typesafe.com/)**?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Exactly as you normally would!

```
val query = for {
  coffee <- Coffees if coffee.name like "%expresso%"
} yield (coffee.name, coffee.price)
```

Will generate SQL like

```
SELECT name, price FROM coffees WHERE NAME like '%expresso%';
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it scala query or slick? For me in slick it only works with coffe.name.like("%expresso%") (with dot separator).

Comment: @Tim: Your syntax is equivalent to the one Faiz presented (note the dot between `coffee` and `name`).

Comment: No it does not sschaef. Faiz's answer has no dot between name and like - so I get a compiler error. If I separate name and like with dot - no error. Why's that? Am I supposed to import some namespace?

Comment: Well if you're using say, mysql,  `import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._` will help. replace `MySQLDriver` with the driver of your choice.

Comment: Does make sense. import slick.driver.ExtendedProfile works fine

Comment: Does anyone know if like does sanitation on the string?

Comment: Just to be aware : this solution allows sql injection!

Comment: if coffee.name like "%${queryStringFromUser}%" <-- This seems to sanitize the string. If it contains \ or ' it will be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got it to work:

```
// argMap is map of type [Str, Str]
val query = for {
    coffee <- coffees if (
      argMap.map{ case (k,v) =>
        metric.column[String](k) like s"%${v}%"
      }.reduce(_ && _)
    )
  } yield(coffee.name)
```

And then you can run this using your db:
`val res = db.run(query.result)`

Of course `res` is a future here that you need to use await to get the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table named, `logs` with 3 fields -

1. id
2. message
3. datetime

You want to perform LIKE operation. So it will be:

```
 def data(data: ReqData): Future[Seq[Syslog]] =  {
      sysLogTable
        .filter(_.datetime >= data.datetimeFrom)
        .filter(_.datetime <= data.datetimeUntil)
        .filter(_.message like s"%${data.phrase}%")
        .result
 }
```

Note: for sysLogTable

```
val sysLogTable: TableQuery[SyslogsTable] = TableQuery[SyslogsTable]
```

```
class SyslogsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Syslog](tag, "logs") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def message = column[String]("message")

  def datetime = column[Timestamp]("date")

  def * = (id.?, message, datetime) <> ((Syslog.apply _).tupled, Syslog.unapply)
}
```

Note: for Syslog case class

```
case class Syslog(
   id: Option[Long],
   message: String,
   datetime: Timestamp
)
```