# slick how to execute LIKE query

Tags: slick-2.0, play-slick

I am playing with PlayScala and Slick. But stocked at how to execute Like query in Slick2. Any Documentation will be more helpful

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE columnA LIKE "%s%";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
val query = for {
  coffee <- Coffees if coffee.name like "%expresso%"
} yield (coffee.name, coffee.price)
```

Will generate SQL like

```
SELECT name, price FROM coffees WHERE NAME like '%expresso%';
```

[REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700821/how-to-use-sql-like-operator-in-slick)